# Play audio files on iOS in a QML program

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, qml, multimedia

In the QML project below, I want to play the audio file (*kimya.mp3*, in the *sounds* folder in the project's directory) when the project is installed on iOS, by touching the green rectangle on the screen.

The *.pro* file:

```
QT += quick multimedia
CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Refer to the documentation for the
# deprecated API to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

ios {
    APP_Sounds.files = $$PWD/sounds/kimya.mp3
    APP_Sounds.path = sounds
    QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA += APP_Sounds
}
```

The *main.cpp* file: (intact, without changes)

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;   
    return app.exec();
}
```

And, this is *main.qml*:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtMultimedia 5.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640; height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        width: 100; height: 100
        color: "green"
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: playExplosion.play()
        }
    }

     SoundEffect {
        id: playExplosion
        source: "file:///Users/Me/QML/soundTest/soundTest/sounds/kimya.mp3"
    }
}
```

The audio file plays on other platforms, say Windows, Android and even Mac, but I don't know where in the code is faulty that when I install this project on iOS whatever I touch the green rectangle, no sound is played!
Do you have any experience in this case, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way more simple is to add the sound file to the qrc and do:

SoundEffect {
            id: playExplosion
            source: "qrc:/assets/test.wav"
            volume: 1.0
        }